# Can't create AWS ALB kubernetes ingress controller in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I used [this repo](https://github.com/naumannt/tf-article/tree/master/Article%205) to create an AWS EKS cluster using Terraform. Now, I am trying to add a an ALB kubernetes ingress controller following [this guide](https://medium.com/risertech/production-eks-with-terraform-5ad9e76db425)

Everything works fine until I try to add the kubernetes cluster role. Then I get this error:

> kubernetes_cluster_role.alb-ingress: Creating...

> Error: Post
> "https://E8475B1B3693C979073BF0D721D876A7.sk1.ap-southeast-1.eks.amazonaws.com/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles":
> dial tcp: lookup
> E8475B1B3693C979073BF0D721D876A7.sk1.ap-southeast-1.eks.amazonaws.com
> on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host
>
> on main.tf line 6, in resource "kubernetes_cluster_role"
> "alb-ingress":    6: resource "kubernetes_cluster_role" "alb-ingress"
> {

With all the other infrastructure in place (or not, I get the same error), here is my minimal  code to produce the error.

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "ap-southeast-1"
  version = "~> 2.65.0"
}

resource "kubernetes_cluster_role" "alb-ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "alb-ingress-controller"
    labels = {
      "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "alb-ingress-controller"
    }
  }

  rule {
    api_groups = ["", "extensions"]
    resources  = ["configmaps", "endpoints", "events", "ingresses", "ingresses/status", "services"]
    verbs      = ["create", "get", "list", "update", "watch", "patch"]
  }

  rule {
    api_groups = ["", "extensions"]
    resources  = ["nodes", "pods", "secrets", "services", "namespaces"]
    verbs      = ["get", "list", "watch"]
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the Kubernetes connection details? Or is it just picking it up from your `~/. kube/config` file? Do you have an old EKS cluster in there that is no longer up?

Comment: It's just occurred to me that I may need to update .kube/config before continuing with the ingress controller deployment in a subsequent terraform run.

Answer (score 0):

Need to copy `kubeconfig` locally to `~/.kube/config` before running a separate terraform manifest for the kubernetes ingress controller. Also set `endpoint_private_access = true` in the eks cluster resource